# How do I create symmetrical and even struts?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I'd like to add some EAS-4 strut connectors between some components to improve the stability of my rocket. But I can't seem to add them with any kind of reasonably symmetry and evenness. The second attachment is entirely free-hand, and it always results in a somewhat crooked strut.

What I'd like to do is just connect two components, e.g. fuel tanks, with the shortest possible connection. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short of using a part welding mod (which in your case might not be appropriate anyways), you're just going to have to live with it.  The best I can explain it is that KSP organizes parts into a [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29), which means a node (in this case, a part) can only have one parent.  The parent of struts is the first part it's attached to.  As to why the second placement doesn't use angle snapping, well that's probably just an oversight, or hasn't been fixed for some technical reason.

As for connecting two parts with the shortest strut possible, that's not really necessary.  Struts weigh the same regardless of how long they are.  Also, it may be better to use a longer strut anyways for structural reasons.  If you really want symmetry, my best advice is to actually use 2 struts and make them cross.  It still won't be perfect, but it's better than some alternatives.